# Implementing a stack using array to support items of different data type

Tags: c++, c, stack

How to implement a stack using array that supports items of different type. 
e.g. It should operate on characters, integers, floats and doubles.

I have implemented it using `void` pointers. Below is the `C` implementation:

```
void push( void** stack, int* top, void* data, size_t size )
{
    unsigned i;
    ++*top;

    stack[*top] = malloc( size );

    for( i = 0; i < size; ++i )
            ( (char*)stack[*top] )[i] = ( (char*)data )[i];

}

int main()
{
    void* stack[10];
    int top = -1, data = 10;
    char ch = 'a';

    push( stack, &top, (void*)&data, sizeof( int ) );

    push( stack, &top, (void*)&ch, sizeof( char ) );        

    printf( "%d ", *(int*)stack[0] );
    printf( "%c ", *(char*)stack[1] );

    return 0;
}
```

The code [works fine](http://ideone.com/7ysFB) for me.

The problem with the above implementation is that the type of data must be known before-hand.

Does there exists a way to implement it without knowing prior information about type of data to be operated [ I know it is not possible in C, Can we do it in C++, if Yes, How? ]?

Comment: [RTTI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information)... though in C++ generally containers are templates that use type parameters. Note there is [`std::stack`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack).

Comment: Yes, containers are templates. But AFAIK, they support only one type at a time.

Comment: Is this in C or C++? `cos the solution will be different for each of those languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your requirement, you can use `boost::any` to achieve this in C++.

```
#include <boost/any.hpp>
#include <vector>

class AnyStack {
    std::vector<boost::any> vec;
public:
    template <class T> void push (const T &e) {
        boost::any v = e;
        vec.push_back(v);
    }
    class Proxy {
        friend class AnyStack;
        std::vector<boost::any> &vec;
        Proxy(std::vector<boost::any> &v) : vec(v) {}
    public:
        template <typename T> operator T () {
            boost::any v = vec.back();
            vec.pop_back();
            return boost::any_cast<T>(v);
        }
    };
    Proxy pop () { return Proxy(vec); }
    boost::any top () { return vec.back(); }
};
```

As others have suggested, you can use RTTI to determine the type of the item in the stack. The example below demonstrates an output routine that does this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream &os, const boost::any &a) {
    if (a.type() == typeid(char)) {
        return os << boost::any_cast<char>(a);
    }
    if (a.type() == typeid(int)) {
        return os << boost::any_cast<int>(a);
    }
    if (a.type() == typeid(float)) {
        return os << boost::any_cast<float>(a);
    }
    if (a.type() == typeid(double)) {
        return os << boost::any_cast<double>(a);
    }
    if (a.type() == typeid(std::string)) {
        return os << boost::any_cast<std::string>(a);
    }
}

int main () {
    AnyStack a;
    a.push(3);
    std::cout << a.top() << std::endl;
    a.push(std::string("hello"));
    std::cout << a.top() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It can be done in C. First you need an enum describing the contained type

```
typedef enum {TYPE_INT, TYPE_CHAR, TYPE_STRING, ... } contained_type_t;
```

Then put everything in a structure

```
typedef struct {
  contained_type_t contained_type;
  union {
    int int_value;
    char char_value;
    void* pointer_value;
    ... and so on ...
  } data;
};
```

You could take a look at the [GObject](http://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/) model and its uses in the [GLib](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.32/), the implementation of *generic* lists which can mix *types* is interesting.

Comment: This approach is widely used. Although it has a restriction that all members of the union cannot have ctors/dectors. Plus the complete list of supported types should be known ahead.

Comment: @KirillKobelev if c-tors and d-tors, this is C++ and so, now standard is C++11, in which members of union can have c-tors, d-tors.

Comment: @KirillKobelev yes with this kind of approach, but the GObject model does  not have this restriction, but it's a bit overkill for a simple stack implementation

Comment: @ForEveR, "member of unions can have c-tors, d-tors" - any details how this can be implemented??